# Kotlin klaxon парсинг Json от google directions api

Tags: google-maps-api, kotlin

Пытаюсь получить дистанцию между двумя точками из ответа google directions используя klaxon ( https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon ) на Kotlin.

как идет парсинг

```
fun distanceDier (start: LatLng, end: LatLng, mode: String) {
    val url = ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=" + mode)
    val result = URL("$url").readText()
    val parser: Parser = Parser()
    val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(result)
    val json: JsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
    println("distance : ${json.string("routes.legs.distance.text")},")
    println("$url") //проверка
}
```

Как вызываю функцию после работы карты:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode === PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode === AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedPlace = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this)
            // тестовы блок
            val place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this)
            val stBuilder = StringBuilder()
            val placename = String.format("%s", place.name)
            val latitude = place.latLng.latitude.toString()
            val longitude = place.latLng.longitude.toString()
            val address = String.format("%s", place.address)
            stBuilder.append("Name: ")
            stBuilder.append(placename)
            stBuilder.append("\n")
            stBuilder.append("Latitude: ")
            stBuilder.append(latitude)
            stBuilder.append("\n")
            stBuilder.append("Logitude: ")
            stBuilder.append(longitude)
            stBuilder.append("\n")
            stBuilder.append("Address: ")
            stBuilder.append(address)
            tvPlaceDetails.setText(stBuilder.toString())
            //тестовый блок
            distanceDier(LatLng(53.402971, 91.083748),LatLng(53.529799, 91.410684),"TravelMode") 
                    // данные беру из позиции маркера и координат в дата классе
                    //но пока для теста(чтобы хотя бы проверить получить дистанцию) забил вручную

        }
    }
}
```

сам юрл
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=53.402971,91.083748&destination=53.529799,91.410684&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=TravelMode

проблема в том что при запуске функции выдает ошибку в полях

```
val result = URL("$url").readText()
```

и

```
 distanceDier(LatLng(53.402971, 91.083748),LatLng(53.529799, 91.410684),"TravelMode")
```

лог

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: ru.kbais.coal4, PID: 4494
                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {ru.kbais.coal4/ru.kbais.coal4.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                           Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                              at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
                                                              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
                                                              at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
                                                              at kotlin.io.TextStreamsKt.readBytes(ReadWrite.kt:144)
                                                              at ru.kbais.coal4.MainActivity.distanceDier(MainActivity.kt:59)
                                                              at ru.kbais.coal4.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:96)
                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 fun distanceDier (start: LatLng, end: LatLng, mode: String) {
    val url = ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=" + mode)
    //val result = URL(url).readText()
    //an extension over string (support GET, PUT, POST, DELETE with httpGet(), httpPut(), httpPost(), httpDelete())
    url.httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
        //do something with response
        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {

            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                val res = result.value
                println("Result: $result")
                val parser: Parser = Parser()
                val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(res)
                val json: JsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
                println("distance : ${json.lookup<String?>("routes.legs.distance.text")},")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что работа с сетью не может выполняться в главном потоке.

Используйте конструкцию `async` для работы с сетью

Приведу полный текст тестового приложения, потому что на **24.10.2017** корутины являются экспериментальными и могут измениться

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.komdosh.testapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CommonPool
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import java.net.URL

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    async(CommonPool){
      val result = URL("http://komdosh.github.io").readText()
      texttest.text = result
      Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
  }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.komdosh.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.12"
}
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделал как написано. подключил библиотеку. выдало следующие: expression async of type int cannot be invoked as a function. the funktion 'invoke' isnot found. C асинхронными запросами еще не работал.Можете и тут подсказать?

Comment: а какую библиотеку вы подключили?

Comment: да что то с 7 библиотек с окончанием R.id.async он предлагает подключить и после выбора каждой из них ошибка. expression async of type int cannot be invoked as a function. the funktion 'invoke' isnot found.

Comment: Снова поменяли, посмотрите исправление, там теперь указывается поток для выполнения

Comment: а ошибка все та же. еще и на UI жалуется

Comment: откопал на гите зависимость compile ' co.metalab.asyncawait: asyncawait: 1.0.0 ' ошибка пропала

Comment: что то поменялось. теперь в логе новая строка с ошибкой и это async {.шапка лога та же

Comment: Написал своё приложение, `async` пока что экспериментальный, его надо включать дополнительными настройками, для несложной работы с сетью нормально работает.

Comment: сделал используя Fuel и все заработало